# MPI Launches more processes than it is initialized with

Tags: c++, c++17, openmpi

Hello everyone I have a problem regarding MPI C++. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

int main()
{   

    int procId, nProc;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);                        
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procId);     
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nProc); 

    std::cout<<"Hello from process "<<procId<<std::endl;

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;

}
```

I compile it using `mpic++ main.cpp -o main`. Then I run it with `mpirun ./main -np 2`. No matter what number I include after `-np` it always launches 4 processes and the output is the following:

```
Hello from process 0
Hello from process 1
Hello from process 2
Hello from process 3
```

This started happening in a large project that I was working on. So, I created a separate small project to test it. What am I doing wrong here ?

I am running Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 64-bit with g++ 11.3.0 and OpenMPI version of 4.1.2. Does anyone know how I can solve the issue?

Comment: I would put `-np 2` in a different order, `mpirun -np 2 ./main`.

Comment: Thanks @alfC. I cannot believe I did this mistake. That did the job!

Comment: Converted to an answer

Answer (score 1):

Please put `-np 2` in a different order.

```
$ mpirun -np 2 ./main
```

`-np 2` (or `-n 2`) is an argument of `mpirun`, not of your program.

(It is still mysterious why you get exactly 4 processes, perhaps you have 4 processors in your computer and `mpirun` tries to be smart.)